# Nginx: How to run my flask application after setting up Nginx and gunicorn?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

How to run my flask application after setting Nginx and gunicorn.

Earlier I used python run.py (http://127.0.0.1:5000/users)

I've tried to run using http://<ip_address>/

Configurations

gunicorn- my-server.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Flask Web Application Server using Gunicorn
After=network.target

[Service]
User=naveen.p@ah.zymrinc.com
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/naveen/Documents/GitHub/flask-demo
Environment="PATH=/home/naveen/Documents/GitHub/flask-demo/myenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/naveen/Documents/GitHub/flask-demo/myenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/naveen/Documents/GitHub/flask-demo/my-server.sock run:app
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

sites-available/my-server

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/naveen/Documents/GitHub/flask-demo/my-server.sock;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

These are my configurations now I want to what to type in postman or web browser to access my API's.

As of now I'm getting "404 Not Found
nginx/1.22.1"